# How to Solve this error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount'

Tags: php, codeigniter

If a program is run in Terminal and Browser this error shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount'

composer.json file code:

```
{
    "require": {
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.18"
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the dependency, install composer and install all dependencies in package.json

Comment: Running `composer install` in project root should resolve your issues. Assumed you have composer installed